# How can I tell if I've been hacked?

Tags: countermeasure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know if I my PC is getting infected?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/how-can-i-know-if-i-my-pc-is-getting-infected)

I'm a home computer user and a programmer by profession.  But my knowledge of security is embarrassingly slight.  What techniques might I use to determine if I've been hacked?  Hopefully something better than antivirus software . . .

Comment: That's kind of a broad question. Do you mean your desktop, server, webapplication, ftp server, ...?

Comment: In addition to @Luc's query, are there any particular symptoms you're experiencing that lead you to think you might be hacked?  Or, are you looking for monitoring options, or just "red flags" to look out for?  As it is, this is a *very* broad question, and quite likely to be closed.

Comment: ...or, there's always the possibility of a duplicate.  Thanks @RoryAlsop.